# Error instantiating java chain-code of fabric-samples

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am having trouble instantiating java chain code on fabric 1.4.3, I did not changed anything, not even the names of the organisations or the channel.
Following are the steps that I followed:

- download binaries using command `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s`
- set the path export PATH=/bin:$PATH
- cd fabric-samples/fabcar
- run the script `./startfabric.sh java`

Then I get this error while instantiating the java chain code

> Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg chaincode registration failed: container exited with 1

Although I can install and run the javascript chain code provided in fabcar sample perfectly.

Platform information

```
Fabric-samples branch : release-1.4
Docker: 19.03.2
Go version: go1.12.7 darwin/amd64
Node version: v8.16.0
OS: Mac Mojave
```

Comment: are you able to provide any information from the docker logs? primarily when the container is being built.

Comment: in the `build.gradle` file in the fabcar contract (`fabric-samples/chaincode/fabcar/java/build.gradle` ) can you change  the url to jitpack to  'https://www.jitpack.io' and see if that helps..

It's around line 29..

Comment: @Calanais I believe it is not able to bring the docker container for the java chain-code up, and with 500 is for internal server error. It can be because of jdk version I think. I am trying to build the java chain-code separately now.

Comment: @Calanais the project builds successfully, so its not related to the jdk version on my local, I checked the jitpack.io url and its same as on website.

Comment: What command do you try to execute? On inatlling java chaincode the path to java project must be absolute to container volume. Can you paste tour install command? Or you just execute a script on demo project?

Comment: @SergioGragera I used the demo project for now which is provided in the fabric-samples repository and followed the instructions from the fabric documentation.

Comment: Based on one of the sample contracts, I've sketched out quickly the minimal steps, purely on the command line using Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.3

https://gist.github.com/mbwhite/73630b4f24acab1e1ece2f726ea526f9

This was from me running those commands this morning, there may be errors and probably typos.. 

Any feedback welcome, and I'll work to getting this properly published.

TL;DR; The monitoring script in that gits is the best tool for helping debug what's wrong

Comment: Then, if you have install the js chaincode and now you are trying to install java chaincode is possible that you need to upgrade your version (if chaincode js is installed with version 1.0 you need to install java chaincode with other version). I don't know if you can do it with scripts.

Comment: @SergioGragera yes I can do that with the script, but I guess name should not be a problem, as I am restarting the complete network to install java chain-code, which is actually the default behaviour of start-fabric script also. But that is actually a nice idea that i should try to install Java chain -code individually.

Comment: @Calanais the compilation of steps is really good, thanks for that. Let me try it out this way too and will let you guys know. 
But just for confirmation, it is possible to access javascript chain-code deployed on the chain via java application and vice-versa, In my opinion it should be but what is your say on that.

Comment: Yes,  it is possible to access javascript chain-code deployed on the chain via java sdk from java application.

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue with `Fabric-samples` branch 1.4 on fabric 1.4.4 .
I updated following dependency from 1.4.3 to 1.4.4 in `build.gradle` file which solved the issue.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.hyperledger.fabric-chaincode-java:fabric-chaincode-shim:1.4.4'
}
```